# why IE8 password field display nothing when we type through keyboard?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, windows-xp

In windows XP mode IE8 browser when user type password only the curser moves the bullets is not showing up.Any body crossed across this situation.I want my user to display what ever they type as bullets in the field

Comment: Gee, who downvoted this question? Just happened to me...

Answer (score 38):

Perhaps you are using Google Web Fonts, or something else other than standard fonts?

Try putting this in your page's <head> tag:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style>
  input {
    font-family: Arial;
  }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Make sure to replace `input` with whatever CSS selector it takes to override the font-family.

Comment: I had the same problem, this solution fixed it. Thanks! Although I used input[type="password"] as the problem only occurs on password inputs.

Comment: My problem was that I was using MS PGothic for the Japanese version of our site but the password fields were showing unusually large dots as the user typed their password. Using the standard font for just the password fields straightened out the size issue.

Comment: Even safer would be to specify a default font, ie: "font-family: sans-serif"

Comment: @JosephWhite The large centered dots are the standard for Japanese password fields, not the asterix like it is in the rest of the world

Comment: Thank You @MarkHosang, Next time I will know not to worry about fixing this problem.